# Python / C++ Fast Gaussian Fit on 4 points

Tags: python, c++, performance, optimization, curve-fitting

I'm trying to do gaussion peak rekonstruktion. The special thing is I need to fit to only 4 points and I need to do that very fast. At the moment I'm using python with scipy curve_fit. It takes about 0.5ms/peak.

- Has someone a good idea how to speed that up? (beside
  parallelization)
- Are there faster things than curve_fit?
- Maybe some special things due to the fakt that I have only 4 Points
  to fit to?
- I'm not fixed to python.

  - Could it be significant faster with c++?
  - Tips for good C++ Libs for that job?

I know that this is a very wide question, so thanks for every helpful Idea or hint were to look at.

Thanks

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. As-is the question is off-topic for SO format.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the noise and dynamic range of your data, you may be able to convert the problem to a linear fit.

Lets assume that you have already removed whatever baseline you might have in your signal, and that the signal is not terribly noisy.  You are trying to fit your data to

[image: y = a e^{- v x^2 }]

Alternatively, you may be able to fit your data to

[image: log(y) = log(a) - b x^2]

In other words, after removing baseline, and provided your data has good S/N, you can take the log of our data (y), the square of your coordinate (x), and fit it to a straight line, for example by simple linear regression.

Aside, I want to mention that there other robust fast methods available when you have more data points on the Gaussian.  For example, if you can take a second derivative (using a filter), the zero crossings correspond to the width of the Gaussian and then there is a simple formula for the height.  In that method there is no need to remove the baseline since the derivative does it for you.

Comment: Okay that's it.  I think I am done editing this.

Comment: Good Idea but I already tried this - it doesn't speed up on my data. The overhead of taking the log and later back to the gaussian parameter with the error propagation compensate the little bit faster fitting.